# Modifiy the default auto implement "template" in VB.net 2015

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

in a class i declare a variable private :

```
 Private test As String
```

then i right click do quick action and generate :

```
    Public Property Test1 As String
    Get
        Return test
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        test = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Do you know a way to modify the autogenerate code produce?
I want to add something like :

```
    Public Property Test1 As String
    Get
        Return test
    End Get
    Set(value As String)

        Tmp_Val = test
        test = value
        RaiseEvent VariableChanged(test, Tmp_Val, VarDesc("test"))
    End Set
End Property
```

if somebody know a place where the "template" is stored?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

quick actions are used for refactoring and pointers toward fixing errors in your code, not so much for automatic code generation. Unfortunately, I haven't found any way to edit these. You can however edit code snippets, but this is laborious to say the least. There is an extension you can install which is supposed to make snippet editing easier - I haven't tried it, but it comes via Microsoft#s Visial Studio Gallery -

[Snippetizer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3260eed5-c3c2-44f8-b705-a332d3a9f64b)

Comment: hi, the big advantage of quick action in this case is that it take the variable i right click on as an argument that is put in the generated code. I manage to modify the code snippet but i didn't find a way to passe a varaible name in parameter to this code. I'll take a look at your link. Thanks